# Finding difficulty in creating SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I am writing a SQL Server 2012 query to create a trigger but I get an error. I have tried several different ways. This is the code that I am using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_table_update
After_hsi.keyrecorddata202_UPDATE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE hsi.keyrecorddata202 
    SET kg563 = hsi.keyrecorddata202.kg275 * ['Price_List$'].Unitprice
    FROM hsi.keyrecorddata202 
    INNER JOIN ['Price_List$'] ON hsi.keyrecorddata202.kg487 = ['Price_List$'].NO#
    WHERE kg568 = 'FOOD'
END;
```

Comment: You should help the people who would help you, by including the exact error message you got. Don't make us guess at it.

Comment: Also use the correct tags for the brand of RDBMS you are using. I changed the tags, because I infer you are using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. You are using square brackets around table names, which is not recognized in MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin but the `FOR EACH ROW` doesn't sound like sql server at all.

Comment: The `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM` syntax is also Microsoft, if I recall. It's not how multi-table UPDATE is written in MySQL.
Perhaps the OP has partially adopted MySQL syntax, after coding on Microsoft SQL Server. Part of their syntax: `After_hsi.keyrecorddata202_UPDATE` is just gibberish. That won't work on either RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is all wrong - check out the [official MS docs for `CREATE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more details.

The trigger should be

```
CREATE TRIGGER (name of trigger)
ON (name of table)
FOR/AFTER (operation - INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or combinations)
BEGIN
    ...
END;
```

and SQL Server **doesn't** support the `FOR EACH ROW` notion - the trigger is always based on one statement, which might have affected **multiple rows** and the trigger runs only **once** for the whole statement (and thus `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables might have **multiple rows** in them - so treat them accordingly!)